# TypeError: Cannot read property 'gManager' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3

I am using angular-google-map.js.
And i am getting error in my console window repeatedly.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'gManager' of undefined
    at Object.fn (ui-googlemap.js:10)
    at n.$digest (angular.min.js:123)
    at angular.min.js:126
    at e (angular.min.js:40)
    at angular.min.js:44
```

How can i deal with? 
My Code
Html File

```
<div id="map-canvas">
        <ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'>

            <ui-gmap-markers models="markerList" coords="'self'" idkey="'intClientID'">
            </ui-gmap-markers>

        </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

And controller file is

```
$scope.map = {
            center: {
                latitude: $scope.lat,
                longitude: $scope.long
            },
            zoom: 11,
            markers: [], // array of models to display
            markersEvents: {
                click: function (marker, eventName, model, arguments) {
                    $scope.map.window.model = model;
                    $scope.map.window.show = true;
                }
            },
            window: {
                marker: {},
                show: false,
                closeClick: function () {
                    this.show = false;
                },
                options: {} // define when map is ready
            }
        };
$scope.markerList = /* Service call to get marker point */
```

markerList get form the service.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: posted the code. @azium

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old one but I would like to bring my experience.
In my case this issue was solved initializing the markerList variable.

While angular-google-maps creates the Markers object, needs to know the length of the array of markers (even if it is 0) and this process breaks if the array is undefined.

So just add

```
$scope.markerList = [];
```

at the first lines of your controller.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. I was missing the `pan` attribute, which the [documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api) specifies is required. After adding the `pan` attribute, the error went away.

Comment: I missed it too, but after I added it, the warning is still exist